# INCOME TAX E-filing - post office saving bank IFSC code? (AY 2017-18)

Tags: income-tax, india, bank-account, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund

My query is regarding IFSC Code for Post Office Saving Bank. 
I tried to find everywhere including visiting the bank but they say they have no IFSC Code. 
Now as per the new income tax form (ITR 1) (AY 2017-18) I have to mention the total accounts held, the bank, account number and IFSC Code. 
If I do not enter IFSC Code it does not allow me to submit the form.

So what to do incase I have Post Office Saving Bank, how can I do my Efiling?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge if you have saving account with post office you can only do transaction inter post office and that too electronic based.

I don’t think post office saving banks have IFSC now. India Post has got bank licence and will migrate its saving accounts into similar system like banking. India Post is not a part of payment and settlement system to make it simple to understand you don’t get a cheque book on Saving Ac in Post Office.